# MIDI out waveforms very different between two devices

Tags: rs232, midi

I have two MIDI output devices: an Axiom49 keyboard and a Korg SQ-1 step sequencer. The Axiom49 drives a MIDI input circuit that I've built using an Arduino just fine. The Korg SQ-1, however, does not work with it at all.

The Axiom49's output is simply 31.25k baud RS-232, which conforms with the MIDI specification. The output on the Korg SQ-1, however, is totally different than I was expecting and does not work with my MIDI input circuit at all.

So, I hooked both of them up to an oscilloscope (across pins 4 and 5 of the MIDI 5-pin DIN connector, coming from the MIDI OUT plug on both devices) to see what their output looked like (screenshots below).

Also worth noting is that I was able to hook the Korg SQ-1 up to a friend's computer using a MIDI-to-USB cable and drive a software synth.

So, does anyone know why the waveforms between two MIDI devices could be so different?

[image: Axiom49 oscilloscope screenshot]
[image: Korg SQ-1 oscilloscope screenshot]

Comment: Can the Korg drive *anything* successfully with that *disaster* of a serial waveform?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It drove a software synth on my friend's laptop last night using a Roland MIDI-to-USB converter.

Comment: that's one tolerant MIDI-USB converter man.  I wonder if there's anything you can do to the Korg to get it to clean up its act?

Comment: Looks broken, or you're on the wrong pins.

Comment: Show your MIDI input circuit.

Comment: @CL. This is the MIDI circuit that I am using: [MIDI IN circuit](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Tutorial/MIDI_bb.png)

Comment: You have linked to the MIDI *output* circuit. Is this really how you have connected it?

Comment: @CL. Wow, I never realized that I was using the OUTPUT circuit. It's weird, because it works fine with the Axiom49.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RS-232 and MIDI are completely different.
In particular, MIDI uses a current loop; the "space" state (logic 0) is defined as a current of (at least) 5 mA.

Depending on the MIDI output circuit, you cannot simply measure the voltage at a bare pin (or between two bare pins) of the MIDI connector.
Your Korg waveform looks as if you tried to measure a floating voltage, and got noise from something else. (And a sample rate of 80 kHz is much too low to capture the actual MIDI signal.)

You have to measure the current by, e.g., connecting a resistor between pins 4 and 5 and measuring the voltage drop over that.

Comment: I'll try measuring a resistor across pins 4 and 5 tonight when I get home from work. I'm curious though -- my Arduino MIDI IN circuit is reading the Axiom49 device just fine as a 31.25k baud RS-232 signal (I'm assuming that's what I'm reading when I'm using the RX pin on the Arduino with the baud rate set to 31250).

Comment: The RX pin would not work with RS-232 signals.

Comment: I bought a PC900 optocoupler last night to build the official input circuit as provided by the original MIDI specification: [Official MIDI input circuit](https://www.midi.org/images/specs/midihw.gif). I'm going to try this tonight.

Comment: Also, I see what you mean about it not being RS-232 now. RS-232 is 12VDC serial communication, whereas the Arduino TX/RX pins use 5VDC serial communication. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The MIDI interface itself does not use a specific voltage; the output/input circuits convert between 5 V logic and the 5 mA current loop. The official circuit can be improved by making Rd 1kΩ and adding a bypass capacitor (see the PC900 datsheet).

Comment: Just curious, any guess as to why the Axiom49 works with my "MIDI input circuit" and shows such a nice square wave on the scope but the Korg SQ-1 does not work with my input circuit and shows a very non-digital looking wave on the scope? Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions or if you've already answered this above -- I'm not very experienced with EE stuff but I'm very eager to learn more about it.

Comment: Apparently, they use different output circuits.

Comment: Got it working tonight. The trick was using that optocoupler input circuit. Both waveforms look the same on the scope now. Thanks for all of your help!